# Mailchimp email template : survey question in a button / survey design improvement

Tags: mailchimp

Using Mailchimp template, is there a way to use buttons to build a survey.

For example I have this working perfectly :

[image]

And I would like to create the survey this way using buttons :

[image]

But when I use the preview or I send an email I obtain this :

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this or a way to improve survey design ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is have is most likely caused by HTML encoding, u should replace `<` by this `&lt;` and `>` by this `&gt;`

1. `<` = `&lt;`
2. `>` = `&gt;`

> Here's an example :

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <!--[if mso]>
          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://litmus.com" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#EB7035" fillcolor="#EB7035">
            <w:anchorlock/>
            <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">I am a button &rarr;</center>
          </v:roundrect>
        <![endif]-->
        <a href="#" style="background-color:#EB7035;border:1px solid #EB7035;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">I am a button &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Additional** : you can use this website to encode you template :

https://opinionatedgeek.com/Codecs/HtmlEncoder